# Primary Key Error In PostgreSQL Database when using Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am developing a website. To test the routes and functions, I added some data to a table, I directly uploaded that data to the database from a csv file.
At this time there were 4 entry to the table.
I went to django admin panel and it showed all the data correctly.
I then added another column to database (a foreign key). After that i tried to enter a new data via django admin panel.
After 4 try (where it showed primary key is already there) it started accepting the entry.
This is second time this has happened with me in a python and PostgreSQL condition. First time it was with Flask using SQLAlchemy. At that time I deleted data mistakenly I inserted via other routes there also.

What is happening here? I have no clue, please help and tell me what I can do to avoid this. Because I can handle 4 or 5 entries, but what will happen when I have to keep trying 100 times.

I have no idea what the problem is and why it starts working after retrying number of rows in the table. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. You added 4 rows to your table then had problems inserting another. Please post those rows, the exact insert and the complete resulting error.

Comment: Pretty obvious, you are entering duplicate data on your retries and that is triggering the Primary Key error. The answer is don't do that. Either DELETE/TRUNCATE the table to start fresh or just INSERT data that is new to the table and UPDATE the non-PK fields on the existing data.